# How to connect Python to a html file

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have written some python code:

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
r = input()
html = urlopen("http://www.google.co.in/"+r._str_())
soup = beautifulsoup(html, "lxml")
print (soup)
```

How do I connect my python file into a html file?
Are there any links? (Like `javascript`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Well, by your comment, I think you mean using python as the backend server language and html as frontend (pretty much like any website).

For that solution, you have multiple ways to do it. You can create your server from scratch, using the base `http.server` from python 3 ([see here for more informations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.server.html?highlight=httpserver)).

You also have multiple ways to do a python-based server, including Frameworks, which are, by today, the best way to do it.

You already have multiple python frameworks that does the server job, letting you defining the routes, data processing etc..

These frameworks include [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), or [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).

A good one to start doing the server-part in python is Flask. The syntax is quite easy to understand, it does the job well, and there's no extra over-complicated work to do. Also, the community is great. ([See here for a good way to start learning using flask](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/)).

Old:
You need to be more precise. What do you want to achieve ?

What do you mean by "connect my python file into a html file" ?

HTML file is not something you can connect to, it's just a basic file.
If you meant to write the html response body into a file just take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm) for file interaction. If not, please be more precise about your problem/question.

Comment: I mean, how can I run my python and html files so that on the server side, python is doing the work while on the client side, html is the UI

Comment: Sorry about that, now the answer should match your first problem.